# Woocommerce set cookie after a sale

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to make my custom cookie to remain on all pages when triggered...

```php
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_setcookie');

function my_setcookie(){
  $path = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_PATH);
  $host = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
  $expiry = strtotime('+2 days');
  setcookie('madeorder', 'yes', $expiry, $path, $host);
}
```

it successfully triggers on thank you page, but when i navigate to another page it is gone...

Have i done something wrong?

Comment: If the goal of the cookie is to implement a thankyou for your sale page, it would be better to ask how to implement a thankyou for your sale page, than to ask for a fix to a problem to a solution to a problem. Eitherway, 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic on this stack, you should contact Woo support, forums, groups, etc